# HTML5: Problema com operador not no atributo pattern do input text

Tags: html5, input

Quero fazer com que o input text permita apenas as seguintes strings:

site.com; site.com.br; site123.com123.br; site-123.com.br.
Mas nunca: site-123-.com.br

A minha expressão ficou assim:

```
(([a-z0-9-]{3,})[^-])+\.([a-z0-9]{2,})(([.]{1})([a-z]{2}))?
```

Dessa forma, quando digito: site.co*/@m.br, ela está aceitando.

Ou seja, quero que aceite traços, mas nunca no final da primeira string ou antes do primeiro ponto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renan,

Montei esta expressão:

```
^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9](\.[a-z]{3,}(\.[a-z]{2})?)$
```

Fiz alguns testes, ela resolve o problema do traço e valida vários nomes de domínio. Veja se atende a sua necessidade.

Comment: Muuuito obrigado, Humberto! Resolvido a minha questão! Apenas vi como você fez na sua expressão, e adicionei pouca coisa a mais na minha, ficando assim: `(([w]{3})\.)?[a-z0-9](([a-z0-9-]{3,}))[a-z0-9]+\.([a-z0-9]{2,})(([.]{1})([a-z]{2}))?`